# в чем проблема? выдает ошибку mysql строка 7,10?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

не могу зайти на сайт, выдает ошибку тип не правильно ввожу пароль от базы данных, но на хостинге у меня такой пароль на бд, я пытаюсь его менять через файзилу в config.php там вроде есть этот путь к бд, подскажите в чем проблема плз[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так у вас ошибка подключения к базе данных. К ней и нужно пароль уточнить. Найдите где у вас на хостинге это можно посиотреть

Comment: так в этом и приколь я вводил пароль тот через который я захожу в phpmyadmin

Comment: Уточните пароль, имя пользователя и название базы данных. И убедитесь что в config.php все эти данные верны

Comment: сейчас выдает ошибку 500 страница не найдена

Comment: Посмотрите на хостинге лог ошибок

Comment: file:///C:/Users/evtushenko.va/Pictures/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9.png 
Посмотри какой из этих логинов надо вводить 1 или 2? оба пробовал вообще не хера

Comment: вы сбросили ссылку внутри вашей файловой системы. скиньте скрин

Comment: не могу скинуть скрин,не проходит

Comment: закиньте на любой файлообменник и скиньте ссылку

Comment: например https://dropmefiles.com/

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/GrX7Z

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/fl1O9 , самое интересное на phpmyadmin я захожу без труда

Comment: Может вы хост неверно указываете. там где mysql оттуда возьмите его

Comment: ну вот этот хост я беру a329530.mysql.mchost.ru, больше нет

Comment: попробуйте вывести с помощью echo непосредственно перед подключением к базе данных все параметры подключения к базе и сравните. может параметры где-то переопределяются на неправильные?